# Width and Height of Element .net MAUI always NaN

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, android-layout, maui

I have a problem getting the actual width and height of an element in maui.
In WPF, I have ActualWidth and ActualHeight which give the rendered size of the element, once the element is loaded.
But in maui it is always NaN.
I have a simple Grid like:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
            <Border x:Name="CenterBorder" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </Grid>

        <Border Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

Now, I just want to get the rendered width and height of "CenterBorder". But the values are never set. I think it has something to do with the layout is completely dynamic but I do not want to use fixed sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you try to get its Height and Width before the app layout the view. You can try to get it in the page's `LayoutChildren` method.

```
    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
        var width = CenterBorder.Width;
        var height = CenterBorder.Height;
    }
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you. I thought after the elements have been loaded, the width would be there, but it is not the case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on when the method is called? I wanted to test it and it seems like LayoutChildren is never called (.net 8)

Comment: It‘s called in my .net 8 project when the contentpage appearing. @RayYago

Answer (score 2):

You need to read width from its Base classes; `View` or `ViewElemement`.

```cs
(CenterBorder as View).Width
```

Make sure that the Page is rendered completely first.

**Update**

After further investigation I see that this is about rendering. When the Page is completely rendered, the width is there.

Comment: I hooked up the loaded events of the view and even of the border itself. But in the event handlers the width and height are always -1, no matter if I cast the border or not.

Comment: It is because it is not calculate yet.

Comment: The `Loaded` event is not the right place, the sizes are only fully calculated in a later step. There are also multiple layout cycles, and the `Width` and `Height` properties will update separately.

Comment: Yes, they have not been calculated at this step. And I have not found any event that informs about this, not even SizeChanged. So I have to do it like in the answer below.